# What does backpropagating through labels mean?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, tensorflow

In tensorflow's documentation for [tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2) it is written:

> Backpropagation will happen into both logits and labels. To disallow
>   backpropagation into labels, pass label tensors through
>   tf.stop_gradient before feeding it to this function.

I do not understand what backpropagation into labels mean. How do we calculate the loss of the labels?